# How to recognize a start bit in asynchronous serial bit stream

Tags: asynchronous, serial-port

I am writing some code for a microprocessor to communicate with an external device via asynchronous serial communication over a single wire.

I can recognize a transition on the wire from low/high (either way), so I can find the bit boundaries.  Given that I know the baud rate the device is using I can then start clocking off bits, so I can read the stream of bits coming from the device.

What I'm struggling with conceptually is recognizing a start bit - finding the start of a byte frame (assuming I'm getting 8 bit, no parity, 1 start bit, 1 stop bit).  I understand that each frame begins with a start bit and ends with a stop bit, but it is my understanding that start and stop bits look like any other bits - so there's nothing special about them that identifies them as start or stop bits (other than their position).

The only way I can think of to identify a start bit is that it will be the first high bit after a sustained idle period - that is, since I'm expecting 8 bits no parity, if I get 9 or more low bits then the line is idle, and the next high bit will be a start bit.  That's all fine, but what if I start listening to the device mid-bitstream and there is no idle time of 9 bits or more on the wire?  I am clocking off bits, but how do I recognize which bit is a start bit so I can read off a byte?  If I'm clocking off bits, then anything in between frames can only be integer multiples of bits (so a stop "bit" can't be 1.5 bits for example), so everything just looks like bits.

I hope I'm making sense...  thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The start bit is what gets your code to receive a byte going.  Best explained with a state machine.  You've got 4 basic states:

- State "wait": sample the data line.  When you see the start bit then start a timer at 1.5 * bit-time and move to state "data"
- State "data": wait for the timer then sample the data line to record a bit.  Restart the timer to 1.0 * bit-time.  Repeat as long as you haven't received all bits.  Move to state "stop" when all bits received
- State "stop": wait for the timer and sample the data line to check the stop bit.  Move to state "error" if it is wrong, add a byte to the receive buffer if it is not.  Back to state "wait".
- State "error": complain.  Wait for deus ex machina to go back to state "wait".

So basic insights from this is that you need the start bit to get the code going that receives a byte.  And that the stop bit is important so you can reliably see the start bit for the next byte.

Comment: Hans, thanks.  I understand that, but the "when you see the start bit" is what I'm trying to figure out.  The device I'm working with powers on and starts emitting a bit stream.  That bit stream may never have a sustained idle period - except at the very start of the stream immediately after power on.  If I start listening to that bit stream but miss the initial idle period, how do I recognize a start bit so I can frame bytes?  I can clock the bits as you say, but the first bit I see could be any bit anywhere.  I have no way of knowing which is the start bit - that I can think of anyway.

Comment: Erm, that's explicit in serial communications.  The receiver has to start up before the transmitter.  There's no hope to synchronize when the receiver starts up late, state "error" will be popular.  Synchronizing this way is well supported in serial port hardware,  the handshake lines signal whether the other end is powered up and ready to listen.  DTR and RTS signals.

Comment: Thanks again Hans.  I was afraid that's what you were going to say.  So if I miss the initial handshake I'm screwed...

Answer (score 0):

I would make your program read the sequences and decipher patterns at one point or another, moving 9 bits back and forth, the data will make sense, depending on the chains you are transmitting. Once a pattern is recognized, maybe recognizing if the data has one period, then I would look if at any point the line of bits that makes a byte match to the period code (ascii 46) then count spaces back and forth and establish the start and stop bits.